# Git deployment fallá al hacer publicación de una aplicación NodeJS en Azure desde Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio, nodejs, azure

Me encuentro publicando desde Visual Studio 2015 una aplicación

- NodeJS
- Express

La quiero publicar en Azure y desde luego utilizando *Git Deployment*. Todo parece normal, pero al momento de ejecutar el website **desde el browser** siempre obtengo error 403.

Esto no sucede cuando hago publicación directa por medio de Web Deployment, pero así no me sirve porque deseo dejar todo funcionando con integración continua por medio de Git.

Para descartar problemas en mi aplicación he creado una aplicación desde el template y tal como está de por sí ya falla de la misma manera.

No logro dar con el error, ¿Alguna idea al respecto?

Sospecho que me debe estar haciendo falta algo en el `web.config` pero no logro dar con el tema.

Comment: _he creado una aplicación desde el template y tal como está de por sí ya falla de la misma manera_ tal vez tengas mejores chances agregando un issue en [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues)

Comment: No lo descarto ;) sin embargo por experiencia previa trabajando con nodeJS en Azure me late que falta algo en el web.config. Veremos si tenemos respuesta y sino nos vamos por el "camino largo"

Comment: Revisaste los logs, revisaste que estas usando el puerto correcto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

después de muchos ires y venires y de reportar un bug en el repositorio de [Microsoft/NodeJSTools](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools) (sin respuesta definitiva aún) logré entender el porqué falla y desde luego encontrar una solución óptima entre varias posibles.

### Diagnóstico

Tras analizar el despliegue me di cuenta que el sitio en azure arroja error de ***forbidden*** porque básicamente el web.config no está cargado en el root y por ende **IIS** no lo puede procesar, al no haber settings IIS queda denegando  el acceso a cualquier recurso.

Aún poniendo luego el web.config en el root haria falta hacer varias modificaciones en el **handler de iisnode** y en la configuración de **url rewrites**

### Solución

Al crear la solución/proyecto - o incluso después - hay que asegurarse que los contenidos del website queden publicados como roots, es decir no crear carpetas adicionales para el proyecto dentro de la solución ya que el deployment se va con la estructura completa de folder.

[image: Deshabilitar carpeta para la solución]

Answer (score 2):

Tuve una situación similar a decir verdad esta no es la solución pero podrías acercarte a ella. Si aún no has activado el debugging en tu site.

Crea un archivo en la raíz de tu aplicación que se llame **IISNode.yml** con el siguiente contenido.

```
loggingEnabled: true
```

Reinicia el site y ejecuta esta línea en tu Azure Command Line Tools

```
azure site log tail [sitename]
```

Para más información puedes entrar aquí

[How to debug a Node.js web app in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-debug/)

Answer (score 2):

El error 403 significa prohibido, usualmente por falta de privilegios.

A mi me pasaba lo mismo cuando cargaba mi app de node.js a azure desde un repositorio gitlab que tenia en una maquina tambien en azure, y resulto ser que el repositorio git no tenia los permisos para ser accedido publicamente. Te sugiero revises los permisos de acceso al repositorio y solo para hacer tus pruebas lo dejes en publico, de esa manera puedes descartar que ese sea el error.